# How do you run this list of command that come from a book Eloquent Javascript Node.js

Tags: node.js

So i have been following along this book about node.js after prepping all the code i run the file,

```
node file-server.js..
listening to port....
done!
```

im using gitbash terminal so i can use curl,
time for some testing
the book wants me to type in the command

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/file.txt
```

it should give a response "File not found"

it wont let me type something in the terminal
instead i went to my browser and typed http://localhost:8000/file.txt
in there it gave me the response

but the book wants me to input another command

```
$ curl -X PUT -d hello http://localhost:8000/file.txt
```

i know its not going to let me type in the terminal but am i missing something?
if i stop the server ctrl+c and then run the command
if will give an error 'refuse to connect'
because there is no server running on that port

these are the commands from the book for testing the server

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/file.txt
File not found
$ curl -X PUT -d hello http://localhost:8000/file.txt
$ curl http://localhost:8000/file.txt
hello
$ curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/file.txt
$ curl http://localhost:8000/file.txt
File not found
```

i want to test all the command
but how to i do that while running the server

yep you guess it, im a beginner :)
here is the link for the full code
https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/file_server.js

my brain cells hurts after reading 19 chapters and now 2 chapters left i'm not going to give up this book. );

Answer (score 4):

Simply run another terminal and test your commands out. As you have rightly put that `ctrl+c` is going to stop the server when you do that in the same terminal.

Comment: YEP i thought of doing that and it works, i just never knew something like that is possible thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Just a small part of this book is about nodejs. Therefore, you do not need nodejs to run the examples. I adapted the most interesting code from the book to run in Vanilla Javascript outside the sandbox:

Take a look at the final links below:

https://www.lcg.ufrj.br/cwdc/3-javascript/